# How to use loops and get outputs in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I have some trouble with the following code:

**Extract_Function(input_id)** is a defined function which used to pull the information from URLs and **input_id** is the input.

** 1 NAME may have multiple Followers_ID

I want to use the loop to extract every element under the first input_id.

```
lst = extract_function('12345')['Followers'][0]
my_output = []
for user in lst:
    data = Extract_Function(user)
    my_output.append(data)

# I am trying to append more DirRptsOrg_IDs to the existing lst
for df in my_output:
    for ids in df['Followers']:
        for q in ids:
            lst.append(q)
```

The sample output for **extract_function('12345')** looks like:

```
NAME      ID       Follower_IDs
John      12345    ['3215','42385','56895']
```

The sample outputs for my_output[0]:

```
NAME     ID       Follower_IDs
Annie    3215     ['45646','7521']
```

How should I use the loop to extract the info until the last person? how to optimize my code above? Thank you for your help.

My expected outputs:

```
NAME     ID       Follower_IDs
John     12345    ['3215','42385','56895']
Annie    3215     ['45646','7521']
Peter    42385    ['46562','871223','11239']
Anna     56895    ['7789','2130','662']
Shawn    45646    []
Frank    7521     ['87963','2356']
...
```